# Traditional IRA taxes: Are withdrawals of contributions taxed different than earnings?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, contribution, withdrawal

Are the contributions to a traditional IRA taxed differently than the earnings when withdrawn and/or are they both considered taxable income when withdrawn?  And at what rate? Capital gain or regular income tax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contributions to a traditional IRA are treated as ordinary income when they're withdrawn, as well as the earnings.

Answer (score 1):

The IRA withdrawals are not subject to FICA withholdings (Social Security or Medicare). Other than that, they are treated the same (as ordinary income).

Edited - to clarify per comment below.

Comment: "the same" meaning as ordinary income not capital gains? thanks